# Are applications limited when screen is put to sleep?

Tags: macos, sqlite

I am tracing a bug in our software which happens so far only on MacOS computers (software runs on Windows, Mac and iOS). It manifests as a timout on starting a transaction in our SQLite database which happens when some other process has already started and not yet finished another transaction or the database did not respond in time (timeout is 30 seconds). Also I noticed in logs that simple http request to check network status take too long. Both SQLite access and network check are scheduled to run in background by our application.

The only time I was able to reproduce this behaviour is when I left our app running on our testing Mac mini and the screen turned off and let it run for a couple of minutes until background processes are started. In energy saver settings we have:

- computer sleep: never
- display sleep: 10 minutes
- put hard disks to sleep when possible: ON
- wake for network access: ON
- other options are OFF

Is it possible, that when the screen is put to sleep, applications are limited in their processing or IO which might then manifest as HTTP requests and SQLite DB access takes too long?

(I hope this is a SuperUser question not a StackOverflow.)

Comment: I can't provide any evidence to back this up except for anecdotal - but I wouldn't expect any halt on screen sleep. I have Macs here that never sleep, but allow the screen to sleep, which remain in active online structures for days or weeks at a time. The particular structures have a 3 minute timeout, so perhaps that makes just enough difference, but they do remain connected.